# Is there a MySQL equivalent of php's Preg_Replace?

Tags: php, mysql, regex

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to do a regular expression replace in MySQL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/986826/how-to-do-a-regular-expression-replace-in-mysql)

When I search the db for a certain value, say a singular noun like "party", I want to be able to get the value "party" from the db, even though it's actually "parties". For that I thought about replacing the -ies suffix for -y, which didn't have any conspicuous exceptions (maybe "lies").

Is there a MySQL equivalent to the PHP Preg_Replace using regex? Can I handle it otherwise without a mysql function?

so:

```
SELECT * 
  FROM table 
 WHERE preg_replace('/(.)*ies/','y',column) 
 WHERE column="party";'
```

Thanks!

Comment: FYI: It looks like you have 2 `WHERE` clauses in your query. This is probably not what you meant to type.