# Mysql call to non existent function

Tags: mysql, function, preg-replace, procedure

I'm having trouble with a MySQL function I pulled across from another db. I did and import of the data and the functions and procedures separately.

I now have a `makehash` function that makes a call to `preg_replace`. I can't see this function or procedure anywhere though.

If I run `show function status` or `show procedure status` nothing to do with `preg_replace` shows up, only the custom procedures and functions that were there before.

Is there something I am missing that is installed on the db I copied from that I have neglected to copy over to the new one?

Here is the `makehash` function:

```
CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` FUNCTION `makehash`(description text, raw_location text, title text) RETURNS varchar(32) CHARSET utf8
NO SQL
DETERMINISTIC
begin
    declare data longtext;
    declare hash varchar(32);
    set data = ifnull(description, '');
    set hash = null;
    if length(data) > 64 then
        set data = lower(concat(data, ifnull(raw_location, ''), ifnull(title, '')));
        set hash = md5(preg_replace('/[^a-z]/', '', data));
    end if;
return hash;
```

Comment: preg_replace is a php function - not mysql. See also: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1815865/is-there-a-mysql-equivalent-of-phps-preg-replace

Comment: @ethrbunny I know but I was wondering if I am not seeing something in the other db. Ideally I just want to copy it over from there. This function works on the other db so I figure it must be there somewhere. Besides functions and procedures are there other things stored in a mysql db?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's likely that the database you copied that function from is using the [lib_mysqludf_preg](http://www.mysqludf.org/lib_mysqludf_preg/) library, which provides, among other things, a `preg_replace()` function for MySQL.  To make use of it, you'll need to download, compile (unless using a prebuilt binary package) and install that library; see the link above for details.

Comment: This was it, thanks. I didn't think it was as I thought maybe they would show up when I list the functions.